# How to "select" multiple rows that have a certain variable value?

Tags: r

I also want to be able to count/sum the number of these rows.

I can't seem to find this answer anywhere and it's so simple.

In Python it's something like:

`df[df[value1]=="<value2>"].count()`

How is this done in `R`?

Comment: *Or is R really that much less intuitive?* - flattery will get you everywhere. Using the example `mtcars` data you can just do - `sum(mtcars$cyl==4)` or `mtcars[mtcars$cyl==4, ]` will return the subset.

Comment: More precisely for your example: `sum(df$value1 == "<value2>")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I just a return of NA.  Specifically, I'm trying to do extract the number of items that have a value of 24.

**sum(df$VALUE==24)**  only gets me 'NA' and I do know there are many values with 24

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment about NA you should be able to combine @kdopen response with is.na() to exclude the NA values in df$VALUE:

```
sum(df$VALUE[!is.na(df$VALUE)]==24)
```